# Javascript(gameQuery game) objs is too many to run normal

Tags: javascript, gamequery

I'm writting a js game with "gameQuery" jQuery plugin, a shooting game.

While there are many bullets (for examples 100 or more), the animation would turn very slowly.

I use code blow for cycling moving DOM, means excute function per 20 millisecond. All bullets are stored in an array,

```
$.playground().registerCallback(function(){
   for(var i = 0; i < bulletList.length; i++) {
     //move bullet
     ...
   }
}, 20);
```

How could I optimize my code to enhance efficiency? Thx!

Comment: You could use CSS3 to animate the bullets, if you aren't already. CSS3 animation takes advantage of the GPU. Also, calculate the length once instead of through each iteration. `for(var i = 0, len = bulletList.length; i < len; i++)`

Comment: `var len=bulletList.length; while(len--){ // move bullet}` but tbh I think you are being too overly concerned with micro optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things I can think of:

1. Are you doing collision detection with the bullets. If yes this is
   probably the point where things slow down since displaying hundreds
   of sprites should be a problem in itself.
2. Are those bullet animated (with more than one frame?) If yes you may
   want do try without animation to see how this impact the
   performances.
3. If all the bullets move in the same direction at the same speed you
   can put them all in a group and then move the group instead.
4. If they don't move in the same direction you can still put them into
   a group. You will then detach this group before moving them all.
   Once you are done you can just append you group again to the game.
5. This one is more complicated to implement but you could try to
   detect that the player fired a series of bullets at regular
   intervals in a given direction and represent them with a single
   sprite with a repeating image of a bullet.

Comment: Thx! @Selim .
1. All the bullets are enemy's bullet and I didn't do any collision detection.
2. Though All bullets are put in one group, every bullet has its own direction. So I have to move all every time with "for" or "while" statement, I think here is the point things slow down.
I still couldn't think out a solution.

Comment: Did you try this. Let say all your bullets are into a group called "bullets". The you can detach the group with: bullets = $("#bullets").detach();

You will then change the position of all your bullets like before.

And finally you will attache the bullets' group back to the document with bullets.appendTo(parentGroup).

Tell me if it helps.

Comment: I had used your method, effect was not obvious with using detach(). And, I couldn't remove outside bullet after detach() util I append it again. :)  I have thought out a better method: window.setTimeout(function(){bulletMove(bullet)}, 50); Use setTimeout in recursion, the result is great, I give up the "while" statement because inefficiency from here. Now things wouldn't slow down even there are 300 or 400 bullets on the screen. Thanks for your help! lol~